# express differentiate dynamic segment and other static segment

Tags: node.js, rest, express

```
const route = Router();
router.get('user/:UserId');
router.post('user/:UserId');
router.put('user/:UserId');
```

I have the above routes for user REST api's,  i wanted to have a user by location api. so i tried something like below.

```
router.get('user/getUserByLocation');
```

The problem is it calls the `router.get('user/:UserId');` as it finds the getUserByLocation as UserId.

I changed the `router.get('user/getUserByLocation');` to `router.get('getUserByLocation');` it works.

My question is , is the above solution the best approach or i need to use the `router.get('user');` with querystring to get the getUserByLocation.

Comment: Which *order* did you put them in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configre `getUserByLocation` before `router.get('user/:UserId')`. Change the order of your code. Configure `router.get('user/getUserByLocation')` first.

In express, the first matching request handler is executed, so if `router.get('user/getUserByLocation')` is configured after `router.get('user/:UserId')`. That will get called before that.

```
const route = Router();

router.get('user/getUserByLocation');

router.get('user/:UserId');
router.post('user/:UserId');
router.put('user/:UserId');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare in router that `:UserId` should be a number (and not a string) using `(\\d+)`. This way `user/getUserByLocation` shouldnt match your route `user/:UserId`:

```
const route = Router();

router.get('user/:UserId(\\d+)');
router.post('user/:UserId(\\d+)');
router.put('user/:UserId(\\d+)');

router.get('user/getUserByLocation');
```